# Why use a singleton to share data between multiple view controllers when you can use NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

Any thoughts on this ?

Thanks for shedding some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is ready made database provided to us. If we use it, we are saving things in database and making fetch operation.

If you want your data to be persistent then use `NSUserDefaults` and/or your own database.

If you want to share data globally and dont want it to be `persistent` then use `singleton` class.

It is based on our requirement if we want a shared class (singleton class) or a database (NSuserDefaults).

Comment: +1: `NSUserDefaults` is for persistent data, especially data that represent application settings.